# Select rows in a table after a pre-set row number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table.

This is the sql to extract the first 20 elements:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY sticky DESC, pub_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

`Sticky` field can be 0 or 1 if the news is sticky or not.

When I want to retrieve next news, I should to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY sticky DESC, pub_date DESC LIMIT 20, 20
```

But meantime another news may have been added, so I have the last news retrieved in first query also in the second query.

Then I save in a variable the `id_news` field of the last news shown, so I can restart from that record, but I don't know how to tell to sql command.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY sticky DESC, pub_date DESC LIMIT (id_news next row number), 20
```

How can I do?

Comment: Receive not 20 but 21 row. 20 - for output, 21th - for to store its `id`.

Comment: @dam034 . . . I don't think this structure is well thought out.  What if 21 rows have `sticky = 1`?

Comment: @Akina I can store 21th id, and after what I have to do? I can't use where condition with the id, because there are the sticky news which can have a smaller id and than reshow them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff 3-4 news are sticky = 1

Answer (score 1):

Since you are ordering by pub_date, you need to use pub_date < then the last pub_date to avoid fetching duplicate rows.  Your first query is:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY sticky DESC, pub_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

Then the follow up queries are:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE active = 1 and pub_date < 'insert_last_pub_date' ORDER BY sticky DESC, pub_date DESC LIMIT 20
```

That will stop duplicate entries from leaking into the query.

Comment: If are there 2 news with the same date? Isn't there a way to select rows next to `id_news`?

Comment: @dam034 I don't see how you could use an id unless you sort by id in the query unless the id and pub_date follow the same ordering.  Is that the case?  Do are the ids and pub_date monotonically increasing in the same order?

Comment: id and pub_date can't be always ordered, because there are sticky that orders first, so I need a query that says: "after that id give me 20 rows"